# saving file position and returning in fortran 90

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am editing a fortran 90 to read a file. A particular file happens to be 'contaminated' with some extra information, so I wanted to attempt a read and then rewind; reread if in error:

```
open(filenum,file=filename,form="unformatted",iostat=ierr) //'direct' access
...lots of stuff...
here = ftell(filenum)
read(filenum,iostat=ierr) var1, var2             //try reading as var1, var2
if(iswrong(var1, var2)) then                     //check if correct
  call fseek(filenum,here-ftell(filenum),1)      //rewind
  read(filenum,iostat=ierr) vara, varb, varc     //read as different type 
endif
```

However, when I compile this program, I get

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_fseek_", referenced from:
      ___myreader__subroutine_name in myreader.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

(I am trying to compile on gfortran (i686-apple-darwin8-gfortran-4.2)). I understand that `fseek` is not a standard fortran routine.

I wonder if there is an alternative. I understand I can do something like `read(filenum,rec=somevalue)` but how can I use this in a similar fashion? I also thought to attempt reading with `read(,advance='no')` for testing and then reading again with `advance='yes'` if it is in the correct format, but this requires a specific format expression, which is not specified. Thank you.

Comment: Where do you get ftell and fseek from? It sounds like you actually would like to do stream IO instead of direct IO...

Comment: Thanks @haraldkl, I get it [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/FSEEK.html) and elsewhere... would my read statements change if I use stream IO instead of direct? It's a large program that I did not write so I think it would be difficult for me to hunt down and modify the rest of the program.

Comment: You forgot the call, in the documentation of gfortran you linked to, it says it is a subroutine, not a function, thus requiring the call. Stream IO would be slightly different, but portable to other compilers.

Comment: Ah, sorry! There *is* a call statement in my actualy code. I was cleaning this up before posting and inadvertently cut it out... I will edit the post -- thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Ah, if I write original fortran code, I will keep that in mind. Alas, this is part of something bigger I inherited so not my choice, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use backspace to go back to the previous record. Traditional Fortran IO is record based, non stream based (like in C)

Answer (score 1):

On Linux and Windows, it is okay in general to compute seek offsets.

However, on record-oriented file systems (OpenVMS, OS/370, NOS, etc.), the value which comes from `ftell()` is a magic cookie and cannot be inspected or processed using trivial arithmetic to compute a new file location.  Instead, use the `rewind` statement to go back to the beginning of a file (if it is indeed seekable).

Comment: Thanks for the insight on `ftell` -- I thought it was an integer of position (like a point in an emacs buffer...). I think `rewind` works but couldn't go back all the way to the beginning though as it is a large file only needed to go back a few records...

Answer (score 1):

There is  another technique for processing input if you are uncertain about the file contents -- in this case sometimes the files contents are incorrect or different -- which is to read into a string, then examine the contents of the string.  If the contents are valid you can use a read statement to read from the string.  Or if the contents are "different", use a different read statement, or take appropriate action.  No rewind or backspace is necessary.  You do have to guess the longest possible line length to declare the length of the string.

Comment: Ah, something like sscanf with fortran... yes... unfortunately it is a fortran unformatted binary file so this type of operation would be a bit more difficult...